# EJB2 project migrating from JBoss4 to JBoss6. Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, jboss

I'm trying to migrate an old EJB2 web service from JBoss AS4 to JBoss AS6. The first two or three times are fine, the jar files got deployed without any exceptions. But after a few times of restarting the JBoss6 server, I got this org.xml.sax.SAXParseException and don't have a clue what to do next. The stack trace is posted below:

```
12:51:59,368 INFO  [DefaultEndpointRegistry] register: jboss.ws:context=statsws,endpoint=EbuildWS
12:51:59,370 ERROR [STDERR] [Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
12:51:59,370 INFO  [DefaultEndpointRegistry] remove: jboss.ws:context=statsws,endpoint=EbuildWS
12:51:59,371 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///localdisk/java/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/ebuild65_primary/deploy/statsws.jar state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///localdisk/java/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/ebuild65_primary/deploy/statsws.jar
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.WSDLException: Cannot parse wsdlLocation: vfs:/localdisk/java/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/ebuild65_primary/deploy/statsws.jar/META-INF/wsdl/ebuild.wsdl
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.getDocument(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:191) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.parse(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:109) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.getWsdlDefinitions(ServiceMetaData.java:293) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc.JAXRPCServerMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXRPCServerMetaDataBuilder.java:97) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.start(UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.java:59) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.internalDeploy(WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.java:123) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121) [:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.getDocument(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:178) [:3.4.1.GA]
    ... 50 more
```

I'm using JBoss-6.1.0-final with JDK1.7.0_60.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check whether the Web Service you have developed is compatible for running on  Apache CXF web services. As JBoss AS 6 ships with Apache CXF web services by default. If not, you either have to make your ws code and bundle compatible with Apache CXF web services, or you have to change the desired web service container in your JBoss.